# azure functions code change deployment from VS

Tags: azure, azure-functions

After deploying my project using zip deploy,Like I always do for this project I am receiving the error message "Functions runtime error Newtonsoft.Json: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'value')." What could be causing this issue?

Comment: can you share the code which you have tried, so that it will be easier to help

Answer (score 0):

This type of runtime error occurs if a null value being passed to the `Newtonsoft.Json` package.
It could be due to *missing dependency* or incorrect configuration setting, and also mainly problem with the input data, or a bug in the code.

- Check the input value of `Newtonsoft.json` library to ensure that all required fields are present and have valid values.
- Validate if the configuration settings are correct.
- Re-deploy the functionapp and check.

[image]

- Check if the Newton.json dependency deployed to function app.
  Function App=> Check in Kudu site (Advanced Tools=> click on Go=> Debug Console=>cmd)=>navigate to `site/wwwroot` open *bin* folder.

[image]